# How to download latest version of cmake?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I have installed cmake like this -

`sudo apt-get install cmake`

But whenever I try to compile my c++ code.. I always get the below error -

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 2.8.7 or higher is required.  You are running version 2.8.2
```

When I did cmake --version I got this -

```
username@phx7b02c-ee1b:~/build$ cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.2
```

Somehow it is not downloading the latest version of cmake? Any thoughts?

I am running Ubuntu -

```
username@phx7b02c-ee1b:~$ uname -a
Linux phx7b02c-ee1b 2.6.35-22-server #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:48:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: what's your program? what's your gcc version? did you `apt-get update` before `apt-get install cmake` ?

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you running? I'm thinking the solution is to run a more recent version with up-to-date repos.

Comment: I have already provided ubuntu version in my code I guess.. Let me know if there is anything I am missing?

Comment: @TechGeeky: Only indirectly. We can *guess* from kernel version 2.6.35.22 that you're *probably* running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. If so, then Joseph R.'s comment is apt: even if you're restricting yourself to LTS releases only, there's a newer version of Ubuntu which *does* have the CMake version you require.

Answer (score 1):

Baseon your `uname -a` you look to be running a pretty old version of Ubuntu: (2.6.35-22-server is the Linux Kernel version). You're likely using the latest version of CMake that's available via packages for your particular version of Ubuntu.

According too this Ubuntu page:[“cmake” package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cmake):

```
The Lucid Lynx (supported) cmake trunk series
  2.8.1-4~lucid1     backports (main)        2010-05-28
  2.8.0-5ubuntu1     release (main)          2009-12-18
```

You're apparently at your latest version available. You might want to check out the Kitware site to see if a newer version is available as a binary installation or try the .deb file from a newer version of Ubuntu/Debian. Use caution with the second approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can always [build it from source](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html#latest), which should not be too much trouble.  Not surprisingly, CMake uses `cmake` to build if available, but according to the `Readme.txt` in the tarball, it will use the system (POSIX) `make` otherwise.

If you are not used to building from source, the major complication for most people is probably working out dependencies.  You need the "-dev" or "-devel" packages, the same as you would if you were using a library in your own code.